# Can't get the bevel tool to do single edge curves

Tags: bevel

I think I messed something up & can't get it back to normal, I used to be able to bevel one single edge ie between two vertices so that it would create a rounded edge, but now its doing corners, doesnt matter if i select two faces or one line its always doing the corners & not what I wanted. I have fresh installed blender 2.81 with no effect & also Loaded factory presets from the preferences tab but still can't get it to act normal.. The re-install done nothing as it still retained my add-ons & other preferences... How can I fix this please...

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please add some images into your question, so it's clear what kind of *corners* you're talking about. You can also [upload your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can try to replicate the issue. It might be a bug.

Comment: In Blender 2.8 the bevel mode (edge or corner) depends on the selecting method. So vert selection mode will bevel verts, edge selection mode will bevel edges. But you can swap between the two if you hit the V button while beveling.